# Conditional storyboarding

Tags: ios, xcode, conditional-statements, uistoryboard

Have read some great tutorials online about the new storyboarding feature of xcode 4.2. I just cant seem to find information on conditional storyboarding. For example making a storyboard where one button can take you to different screens based upon the value of a boolean variable.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? There are almost always multiple solutions to a particular problem. To me, it sounds like you should be using tags and switches.

Comment: Hmm not sure how to rephrase my question. Currently in the new xcode storyboard feature i have the ability to add a round rect button on a viewcontroller(screen). I can now link this button to a second view controller so when its clicked it takes me there. This happens behind the scenes and no code is generated for me to add /modify any of this behavior..atleast from what i can see. What i want to do is use the storyboard so instead of taking me to the second view controller it will take me to the third based on the condition of a variable.

Comment: I've been looking around a bit and haven't found a good solution here -- it seems you have to have an existing segue in the storyboard and then use it.  (Or have access to your next viewController as a property to create a programmatic segue, kind of defeating the point of segues) That means (for me) that I will create an unused item that has a segue, give it a tag, and then call that segue with my tag via an action on the button.  Seems like there should be a better way.  :/

Comment: Apparently I would post this just before finding an acceptable answer...  you can apparently connect each view controller with a segue then call it programatically.  found this method which seems to do the trick;  connect your view controllers with the segue then call it programmatically.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190980/ios-make-seque-wait-for-login-success

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This scenario is addressed in episode [7 of the Stanford 2011 lectures on iOS development](http://itunes.apple.com/au/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id480479762), on Universal Applications. Setup a target action for the button and in the code use performSegueWithIdentifier to a different segue.

This also allows you the flexibility to have an iPad version which doesn't do a segue because the desired view is already onscreen in a split view.